# Service methods not being called

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am stuck with this code. Then i run Client doesn't display Check string. Can't figure out why this doesn't work. Maybe if you look at this might find the problem?

```
public class ClientApplicationTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException 
    {
        try
        {
            Context jndi = new InitialContext();

            BoatManagementServiceRemote service = (BoatManagementServiceRemote)
                    jndi.lookup("java:global/BoatManagement/BoatManagementServiceImplementation!com.boatmanagement.service.BoatManagementServiceRemote");

             Client cl = new Client("Mark", "Markus", "Birzu 12-44 Street", "+44 333 666 7", "markoff@test.com");
             service.updateClient(cl);
        }
        catch (NamingException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

here is my BoatManagement method:

```
@Stateless
public class BoatManagementServiceImplementation implements BoatManagementServiceRemote 
{   
    @EJB
    private BoatDataAccess dao;

    public void updateClient(Client client) 
    {
        System.out.println("Check!");
        //dao.updateClient(client);
    }
}

@Remote
public interface BoatManagementServiceRemote 
{
    public void updateClient(Client client);
}
```

So actually my `updateClient` methods is not being called at all. Can't see the problem. I use Glassfish and deployment is successful.

Comment: Are you sure there is no output anywhere? Can you make `updateClient()` method return something and check return value? Or maybe throw a `RuntimeException`, it's easier to spot.

Comment: get have warning: INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available by default. But this should not effect.

Comment: Ok, if I make `updateClient(Client client)` return integer 1. I returns me 1, but I doesn't displays me 'Check!' string.

Comment: I don't know Glassfish, but it either suppresses `System.out` completely or redirects it to some log file. You shouldn't use `System.out` in EE application, consider [tag:logback] and [tag:slf4j].